# Adding vertices to polygon in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

For example I have rectangular polygon (4 vertices). I want to add mid-point on each line of the polygon, so in total now I have 8 vertices. And from them I want to build new polygon who will have same exterior footprint, but have 8 vertices:
[image]

What I did and it's not working (I want to do this on every polygon in my buildings.shp): (pseudo algorithm, I'm working with "WITH... AS")

1. Get all original vertices (The 4 black) `ST_DumpPoints` on buildings twice(!)

   Prepare borders of the multi-polygon buildings as line-strings in order to apply ST_Line_Interpolate_Point-
2. All possible lines between same polygon vertices: `ST_MakeLine(points1.geom, points2.geom) WHERE (points1.path <> points2.path) AND (points1.id = points2.id)`
3. Buildings borders: `ST_ExteriorRing(the_geom) ON (ST_Dump(build.geom)).geom AS the_geom`
4. From lines @ 2 select only the border lines: `St_touches(build.geom, lines.geom) AND St_touches(border.geom, lines.geom)=false AND lines.id = build.id AND lines.id = border.id` --all points from same building, all lines from same building have same id belonging to the building
5. Get the mid points: `ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(border_lines.geom, 0.5)` (green points)
6. `UNION` points @ 1 and points @ 5

Now the problem is that I don't have any order in the points @ 6 so it's almost impossible to use `ST_MakePolygon`, and tricks with `ST_ConcaveHull` & `ST_ConvexHull` also not working because they ignores the mid point and eventually I return to where I started.

Comment: Assembling well-known text from this data would seem to be the easiest way to to accomplish this task, walking from vertex 1 to vertex N-1, and adding the midpoint  between vertex *i* and *i+1*.

Comment: @Vince How can I make this iteration?

Comment: @Vince It's important to re assemble the points to new polygon from the new vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ST_Snap http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Snap.html as the final step. As input geometries you need your original polygon and extra vertices to be added as MultiPoint. The third term of the function is snapping tolerance.

[image]

```
SELECT ST_Snap(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 7 7, 7 11, 11 11, 11 7, 7 7 ))'),
ST_GeomFromtext('MULTIPOINT (( 11 9 ), ( 7 9 ), ( 9 11 ), ( 9 7 ))'),0.01);
```

Result is a polygon that has new vertices added from the MultiPoint:

> POLYGON (( 7 7, 7 9, 7 11, 9 11, 11 11, 11 9, 11 7, 9 7, 7 7 ))

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for because my original problem was as documented there: problems with intersection calculations

Answer (score 6):

A simple alternate solution might be ST_Segmentize(). This function will add vertices to your polygon such that no segment is longer than a given length. If getting using the exact midpoints is important, then it's no good, but it's great if you are really just looking to add complexity to your geometry.

Comment: This is the most important answer about "Adding vertices to polygon"  when we preparing before apply st_transform()!  Typical need when transforming from plane (e.g. UTM) to WGS84 LatLong.