# How to find the "first" intersection of a line with anything else

Tags: algorithm, topology, predicates

I am trying to find the first intersection of a line with anything else.

By first intersection I mean the first intersection, if you follow the line in its direction from start to end.

Check the image below, it should make it clear. Black is a line, blue is another geometry, here a polygon, red is the point I am looking for.

[image: Line, Polygon and first intersection]

Maybe there is some standard algorithm for this that I am not aware of? Or maybe a combination of multiple ones?

I am not interested in solutions of closed-source software.

Comment: As Mac and Tosh discovered in the classic Looney Toons short, the definition of "first" is dependent on order of execution.

Comment: Yeah but a linestring has a start and an end if you consider a standard Simple Feature ordered list of points as its "body".

Comment: If you break the line at the Polygon boundaries,  wont the polyline containing the start point have the first node at it's end?

Comment: It can be more complicated than that. Computationally, there may be an advantage to fiipping the coordiate stream.

Comment: Oh, I like that idea @klewis! I think that should be bug free or does someone see a problem with that approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piece-wise example about how to do it with PostGIS functions http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html and http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Line_Locate_Point.html

1. Find intersection points of the linestring and the exterior of the polygon.

> ```
> select ST_AsText(
> ST_Intersection(
> ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING ( 440 280, 760 480 )'),
> ST_ExteriorRing(
> ST_geomFromText('POLYGON (( 500 400, 620 480, 740 360, 640 280, 500 400 ))'))))
> ```

```
"MULTIPOINT(555.66265060241 352.289156626506,673.846153846154 426.153846153846)"
```

2. Find the distance to each intersection point

> ```
> ST_Line_Locate_Point(
> ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING ( 440 280, 760 480 )'),St_GeomFromText('Point (555.66265060241 352.289156626506)'))
>
> 0.361445783132531
>
> ST_Line_Locate_Point(
> ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING ( 440 280, 760 480 )'),St_GeomFromText('Point (673.846153846154 426.153846153846'))
>
> 0.730769230769231
> ```

The first point is located at length of 36.14% from the start point and it is closer that the latter (73.07%).

**EDIT**

However, if the aim is to get the shortest direct distance to the intersection points, it can be found with http://postgis.net/docs/ST_StartPoint.html and http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html. Example with the same points as above.

> ```
> select
> ST_Distance(ST_StartPoint(
> ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING ( 440 280, 760 480 )')),St_GeomFromText('Point (555.66265060241 352.289156626506)'))
> 136.394907933349
>
> select
> ST_Distance(ST_StartPoint(
> ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING ( 440 280, 760 480 )')),St_GeomFromText('Point (673.846153846154 426.153846153846)'))
> 275.762525398578
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this will fail if the shapes of the geometries are such that the first intersection actually is further away than others. Think many meandering curves.

Comment: The function ST_Line_Locate_Point is measuring the distance by following the line. Isn't that just what you want: If you follow the path, how long have you walked when you cross the border for the first time? Or do you want to know the shortest direct distance?

Comment: Oh ouch, I misread it. Yes, ST_Line_Locate_Point seems perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative SQL method based on the suggestion of @klevis.

- Split linestring with the outer ring of the polygon
- Result is a GeometryCollection, select the first part of the collection
- First part should be the one with the original starting point, so select the last point of that first part and you have found the answer.

> ```
> select ST_AsText(
> ST_EndPoint(
> ST_GeometryN(
> ST_Split(
> ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING ( 440 280, 760 480 )'),
> ST_ExteriorRing(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 500 400, 620 480, 740 360, 640 280, 500 400 ))'))),1)));
>
> "POINT(555.66265060241 352.289156626506)"
> ```

I am not sure if ST_Split is guaranteed to keep the order of the parts and it might be good to add a test that the start points of the original line and the selected part are equal. If not, select next part with ST_GeometryN and loop as long as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution in theory which always should work, but require multiple queries and I only provide for postgis:

- select intersection points ([How do I get the points where a line crosses a polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171611/how-do-i-get-the-points-where-a-line-crosses-a-polygon))
- add these points to lines as nodes using st_snap ([Adding vertices to polygon in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160134/adding-vertices-to-polygon-in-postgis))
- extraxt the points of the linestring (with id) with path number ([How to extract POINT from a [LINE|MULTILINE]STRING](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41923/how-to-extract-point-from-a-linemultilinestring))
- overlap intersection points with extracted points the smallest matching path number point will be your first intersection point (order by lineid)